# Modify invoice in QuickBooks gives exception "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream."?

Tags: c#, xml, quickbooks

I am using Quickbooks SDK (qbxml) for desktop for modifying an invoice and I am getting an error "**QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream**." I am using C# as the development language. I am using the "Other" and "FOB" fields for showing the UPS shipping details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
 <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
  <InvoiceModRq requestID="2">
   <InvoiceMod>
    <TxnID>18D23-1422298930</TxnID>
    <EditSequence>1423512371</EditSequence>
    <Other>1ZAV49630440508209</Other>
    <ShipDate>2015-02-03</ShipDate>
    <FOB>2015-02-04</FOB>
   </InvoiceMod>
  </InvoiceModRq>
 </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Whats wrong in this?

Comment: Just a wild guess but since the Xml looks fine at a first glance maybe the parser chokes on the date string formats because it expects `<FOB>02/03/2015</FOB>` instead of `<FOB>2015-02-03</FOB>`

Comment: Hi Filburt, it didnt work. Also, when I modify one field at a time, its working fine. for example, if I take off "Other" and "ShipDate" and retain "FOB" it will update successfully.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not familiar with the QuickBooks SDK so I'll have to leave it to the real pros here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the elements in qbXML *is important*.

If you refer to the documentation:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Or some FAQs out there:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_FAQ#What_does_.220x80040400_QuickBooks_found_an_error_when_parsing_the_provided_XML_text_stream..22_mean.3F

You'll notice that it specifies this order (FOB, then ShipDate):

```
...
<FOB >STRTYPE</FOB> <!-- optional -->
<ShipDate >DATETYPE</ShipDate> <!-- optional -->
...
```

While you specify this order (ShipDate, then FOB):

```
...
<ShipDate>2015-02-03</ShipDate>
<FOB>2015-02-04</FOB>
...
```

Fix the order of your XML elements, and you'll be all set.